# How to get local computer's hardware profile guid by java

Tags: java, windows

How can i retrieve information (guid) about the current hardware profile for the local computer. Like [windows api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724311(v=vs.85).aspx) of C++ below:

```
    BOOL WINAPI GetCurrentHwProfile(
       _Out_ LPHW_PROFILE_INFO lpHwProfileInfo
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following registery item:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles\0001
```

```
private String getLocalHwProfileGuid() {
   String regKey = "SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
   return WinRegistry.getString(
       WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,  //HKEY
       regKey,
       "HwProfileGuid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer